# JPA & PostgreSQL: How do I call a stored procedure with void return type?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, plpgsql

I'm trying to call a PL/pgSQL function that executes an update (language sql, returns void). I'm getting this exception:

`Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.`

persistence.xml:

```
<named-native-query name="Clinic.deactivateByNotFoundInIncomingClinic">
    <query>
        <![CDATA[
            select apply_incoming_clinic_deletions(?)
        ]]>
    </query>
</named-native-query>
```

DAO:

```
public void deactivateByNotFoundInIncomingClinic(long clinicSystemId)
{
    em.createNamedQuery("Clinic.deactivateByNotFoundInIncomingClinic")
            .setParameter(1, clinicSystemId)
            .executeUpdate();
}
```

Help!

**Update:**

Using EclipeseLink on GlassFish 3.1.1 talking to PostgreSQL 9.0 database via PostgreSQL 9.0-801 JDBC 4 drivers.

Comment: If you can run that SQL statement directly (psql or pgAdminIII), you can isolate the problem to the database or to intermediate code. Other things to check: does the function's return value match the declared return type? Is the update performed in spite of the error message? Is JPA and PostgreSQL up to date? Did you try increasing the log levels or debug levels to get more information?

Comment: @Catcall please read the question again. The function has no return type. The SQL statement (`select apply_incoming_clinic_deletions(1)`) runs just fine on its own.

Comment: The function has a return type; its type is `void`. There have been identical error messages in earlier versions of PostgreSQL when a function returned (or tried to return) something other than its declared type.

Comment: If the SQL statement works outside of JPA, it seems to me the problem must either be data, your code, JPA, or the database connector. (Does JPA have its own, or does it use JDBC?) Maybe the database connector isn't prepared to deal with the subtlety Erwin Brandstetter points out below.

Comment: I had the same issue (I'm using different JDBC wrapper library, though) and I was able to fix it by using [`execute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) instead of [`executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the DAO code to this worked:

```
public void deactivateByNotFoundInIncomingClinic(long clinicSystemId)
{
    em.createNamedQuery("Clinic.deactivateByNotFoundInIncomingClinic")
            .setParameter(1, clinicSystemId)
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where this comes from. Your function definition is missing in the question.
But you could try a `plpgsql` function instead of `sql`. Their return type is subtly different when declared as `RETURNS void`. Consider this demo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sql()
  RETURNS void AS
'UPDATE foo SET id = id+1 WHERE id = 34567'
  LANGUAGE sql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_plpgsql()
  RETURNS void AS
$$
BEGIN
UPDATE foo SET id = id+1 WHERE id = 34567;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now, VOID is fictive type. While the plpgsql function actually returns VOID, the SQL function seems to return NULL. I am not sure myself why this is.

```
db=# SELECT f_sql() IS NULL;
 ?column?
----------
 t

db=# SELECT f_plpgsql() IS NULL;
 ?column?
----------
 f
```

Comment: No idea whether this is the source of the OP's problem, but +1 for noticing the difference in returns.

Comment: @Catcall: I was pretty puzzled myself. I actually posted a [question about that with more details](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8319986/939860).

Comment: Yes, there is a difference when executed outside JPA, but I got the same result from within JPA (EclipeseLink on GlassFish 3.1.1 using PostgreSQL 9.0-801 JDBC 4 drivers talking to PostgreSQL 9.0 database). However, when I changed `executeUpdate()` to `getSingleResult()` it worked using language plpgsql. By that time, I had changed the body of the function such that I couldn't revert to `language sql` to see if that had a part to play in this. I'll test shortly with another function.

Comment: I tested the other function. Changing `executeUpdate()` to `getSingleResult()` is all that's required to make this work. The choice of `sql` vs. `plpgsql` makes no difference.

Comment: @SteveTaylor: Thanks for the feedback. That's what we should expect, good to have confirmation. It makes sense, that you can't call `.executeUpdate();` for a function, as for the client it is not an `UPDATE` statement, but a function - even if an `UPDATE` is all that is inside.

Answer (score 1):

**procedure**

```
DROP FUNCTION updatename(bigint);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updatename(var_id bigint) 
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE


BEGIN
    update person set
        name ='lucas'
    where id=var_id;

RETURN;

END;$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

//call procedure

```
Long id=50;
Query  query = emProvider.get().createNativeQuery("SELECT updatename(?1)") ;
        query.setParameter(1,id);
        query.executeUpdate();
```